# Do I need to edge instead of set a pin that is considered a "strobe"?

Tags: signal, display, terminology

I am trying to get the [NHD-320240WG](https://newhavendisplay.com/content/specs/NHD-320240WG-BxTFH-VZ.pdf) display to run using my 8 bit hobby computer. I have successfully gotten this display to work with an Arduino and have ported the code to 6502 assembly.

When measuring all signals, everything looks fine. The right signals and data are sent (I checked with a logic analyser), and I can see the display resetting, but not displaying any data.

[image]

The only thing that is different between the Arduino and 8-bit computer is the /RD signal. According to the [documentation](https://newhavendisplay.com/content/app_notes/S1D13700.pdf):

> When the Generic host bus interface is selected, this pin is the
> active-LOW read strobe (RD#). The S1D13700F01 data
> output buffers are enabled when this signal is low.

so, I have this pin hardwired to +5V, as I never need to read anything from the display.

In the Arduino version though, this pin gets a single rising edge, before the reset sequence:

```
  DDRC = 0xFF;         //set PORTC (control signals) as output, this includes /RD
  PORTC = 0x00;
  DDRA = 0xFF;         //set PORTA (data signals) as output
  PORTA = 0x00;
  pinMode(CS,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RD, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(WR, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RES, LOW);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(RES, HIGH);
  delay(100);
```

I am a little confused by the term "strobe" in the datasheet, as that seems to be a pulse, making me think this signal should see a low-to-high to work. Even though it says the output buffers are enabled when the signal *is* low (as opposed to *becomes*).

Comment: I think the NHD-320240WG display has configured the S1D13700F01 controller to use _Generic Indirect_ host interface mode, based upon which signals are shown on the _Pin Description and Wiring Diagram_ on the display datasheet. The S1D13700F01 datasheet _Table 11-2 Generic Indirect Addressing Command/Write/Read_ suggests should be OK with /RD pulled high as just means can't perform a ``Parameter Read [P#]`` operation (given no need to read from the display). Can you edit the question to include the logic analyser capture from the non-working case, as that may help to identify the issue.

Comment: @ChesterGillon My main question was about that pin. Turned out it was working, I just needed to clear the display first by writing all zeroes.

Comment: For the LSA capture can you edit the question to confirm (a) if ``/RES`` is ``/RESET`` on the display. (b) What ``RS`` is connected to as doesn't match any signal on the display (c) Why ``/RD`` is shown but not ``/WR``.

Comment: @ChesterGillon `/RD` should have been `/WR`, `RS` is `A0` and yes `/RES` is `/RESET`. See updated picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The right signals and data are sent (I checked with a logic analyser), and I can see the display resetting, but not displaying any data.

Section *7.2 Reset Timing* of the S1D13700F01 [datasheet](https://newhavendisplay.com/content/app_notes/S1D13700.pdf) contains:

> A delay is required following the rising edges of both RESET# and VDD to allow for system stabilization. This delay allows the clock used by the internal oscillator circuit to become stable before use. The **LCDC must not be accessed before the oscillation circuit is stable**.

Where the *Oscillator stable delay* is a minimum of 3 milliseconds:

[image]

The LSA capture in the question shows an attempt to write to the display within tens of microseconds after the rising edge of `/RESET` and therefore operation of the display may not be reliable.

Suggest that insert a minimum delay of 3 milliseconds after the rising edge of `/RESET` before attempting to write to the display.

> I am a little confused by the term "strobe" in the datasheet, as that seems to be a pulse, making me think this signal should see a low-to-high to work.

I think the NHD-320240WG display has configured the S1D13700F01 controller to use Generic Indirect host interface mode, based upon which signals are shown on the *Pin Description and Wiring Diagram on the display datasheet*. The S1D13700F01 datasheet *Table 11-2 Generic Indirect Addressing Command/Write/Read* suggests should be OK with /RD pulled high as just means can't perform a `Parameter Read [P#]` operation (given the question mentions the application has no need to read from the display).